# How to get only the text part from tweets extracted using Tweepy?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, twitter, twitter-streaming-api

I am doing a research project on something similar to sentiment analysis. I have extracted tweets from twitter using Tweepy. 
The data I get is something like this:

```
{"created_at":"Sat Apr 22 07:28:47 +0000 2017","id":855684794939842560,"id_str":"855684794939842560","text":"#PL | FIXTURES - 22 April 2017 \nWest Ham v Everton 16:00\nHull v Watford\nSwansea v Stoke \nBournemouth v Middlesbrough #CCFMSport","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter Web Client\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":256051042,"id_str":"256051042","name":"Ayanda Frances Felem","screen_name":"AyandaFelemZA","location":"Cape Town, South Africa","url":"http:\/\/ccfm.org.za","description":"Sports Producer\/Reporter for @RadioCCFm, Views are my own. ayanda@ccfm.org.za","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":446,"friends_count":1648,"listed_count":23,"favourites_count":1625,"statuses_count":16110,"created_at":"Tue Feb 22 15:15:38 +0000 2011","utc_offset":7200,"time_zone":"Pretoria","geo_enabled":true,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"000000","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme11\/bg.gif","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme11\/bg.gif","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"DD2E44","profile_sidebar_border_color":"000000","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"000000","profile_text_color":"000000","profile_use_background_image":false,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/850335374446665728\/BvVIo7oB_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/850335374446665728\/BvVIo7oB_normal.jpg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/256051042\/1491570881","default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"is_quote_status":false,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[{"text":"PL","indices":[0,3]},{"text":"CCFMSport","indices":[117,127]}],"urls":[],"user_mentions":[],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"en","timestamp_ms":"1492846127625"}
```

Now I want to extract only the tweet 'text' from this file. I have tried this:

```
import json

tweets_data_path = 'twitter_streaming.txt'
tweets_data = []
tweets_file = open(tweets_data_path, "r")

json_load = json.load(tweets_file)
texts = json_load['text']
coded = texts.encode('utf-8')
s = str(coded)
tweets_data.append(s[1:-2))
print tweets_data
```

But I get a error saying:

> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tried looking for the reason of this error but didn't find anything concrete.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
null,false = None,False
a = {"created_at":"Sat Apr 22 07:28:47 +0000 2017","id":855684794939842560,"id_str":"855684794939842560","text":"#PL | FIXTURES - 22 April 2017 \nWest Ham v Everton 16:00\nHull v Watford\nSwansea v Stoke \nBournemouth v Middlesbrough #CCFMSport","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter Web Client\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":256051042,"id_str":"256051042","name":"Ayanda Frances Felem","screen_name":"AyandaFelemZA","location":"Cape Town, South Africa","url":"http:\/\/ccfm.org.za","description":"Sports Producer\/Reporter for @RadioCCFm, Views are my own. ayanda@ccfm.org.za","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":446,"friends_count":1648,"listed_count":23,"favourites_count":1625,"statuses_count":16110,"created_at":"Tue Feb 22 15:15:38 +0000 2011","utc_offset":7200,"time_zone":"Pretoria","geo_enabled":true,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"000000","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme11\/bg.gif","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme11\/bg.gif","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"DD2E44","profile_sidebar_border_color":"000000","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"000000","profile_text_color":"000000","profile_use_background_image":false,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/850335374446665728\/BvVIo7oB_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/850335374446665728\/BvVIo7oB_normal.jpg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/256051042\/1491570881","default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"is_quote_status":false,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[{"text":"PL","indices":[0,3]},{"text":"CCFMSport","indices":[117,127]}],"urls":[],"user_mentions":[],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"en","timestamp_ms":"1492846127625"}
print a["text"]
```

I simply used this line of code and it returned me the following output.

```
#PL | FIXTURES - 22 April 2017 
West Ham v Everton 16:00
Hull v Watford
Swansea v Stoke 
Bournemouth v Middlesbrough #CCFMSport
```

Though question is unclear, were you looking for this text?

Comment: yes this is exactly what I am looking for but could you tell me where did you use this print a["text"]. Thanks a lot mate.

Comment: Ok I get what you did but for this I had to change all the false to False and null to None

Comment: @Liam yes I have edited my answer so that it could be of more help to you!

Comment: @Liam hope it was of help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This code is working as expected -

```
import json

tweets_data_path = 'twitter_data.txt'
tweets_data = []
tweets_file = open(tweets_data_path, "r")

json_load = json.load(tweets_file)
texts = json_load['text']
print(texts)
```

The below code part is not needed if the expected output is-

```
coded = texts.encode('utf-8')
s = str(coded)
tweets_data.append(s[1:-2))
print tweets_data

#output
'''
#PL | FIXTURES - 22 April 2017 
West Ham v Everton 16:00
Hull v Watford
Swansea v Stoke 
Bournemouth v Middlesbrough #CCFMSport
None
'''
```